# Is there a way to show an exponent as a superscript when outputing as string?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a plot using PGplot. When creating the title of the graph, the function (math function not c++ function) has an exponent in it, is there anyway to show the function as a proper exponent (superscript) and not just using "^".

Title of plot currently: `y(t) = 1 - e^(-at)`

String within source code for the title: `cpglab("t", "y", "y(t) = 1 - e^(-at)");`

The first 2 arguments within `cpglab()` are the x and y-axis title, by the way.

Comment: nothing to do with c++ - might be something to do with pgplot. please retag accordingly

Comment: Display the exponent, with enough preceding spaces as the first line, then the remainder of the equation on the next line.

Comment: Formatting a string's output is a separate operation from just the string itself. There is nothing provided in the C++ language to indicate in a string itself whether certain characters are to be rendered differently than other characters. That is what markup languages are meant for, like HTML, etc.